# Can we please remove the JTab plugin (or at least make it optional)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm currently trying to format an answer, and it's being a huge headache. It normally would be *really* simple, all I need is to apply preformat to some portions, but because the spawn from hell known as JTab is active, I can't (and for some reason the  tags are not working deep in the answer).

(Dom has now solved the formatting issue in my answer -thanks-, but the point still stands strong)

No one ever uses JTab, and the only times we see it is when someone uses it by mistake, completely messing up the question or answer.

Can we remove it, or at the very least make it optional?

Comment: I've actually already asked a similar question before: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/768/being-able-to-toggle-on-jtab-instead-of-being-on-by-default

Comment: Duplicate? It was discussed a year ago, and I'm adding the suggestion to remove it. In this context, I don't think this qualifies as duplicate. I don't mind as long as something is being done anyway. Should we wait for graduation to bring this to the table again? It has been requested several times.

Comment: `all I need is to apply preformat to some portions` -- that's literally what `<pre>` is for.  If there's some remaining issue with how to use it, ask away, but removing features that some *do* use and was widely requested before we had it needs a better reason.

Comment: @MatthewRead I know what pre does, that's what I meant by tags, the <pre> tags. They weren't working because some weird interaction. And let's be honest, almost no one uses the JTab plugin.  Every single time I see it is someone using it unintentionally. It's more annoying than helpful. There's absolutely no reason for it being active by default.

Comment: I think the reason it's active by default hearkens back to when guitars.SE was merged with this site. They used it more often, and so the imported questions required it. I agree that it's ridiculous to have it on by default for all questions on this site now -- the resolution I like best would be to have it active only on only for questions with the guitar tag.

Comment: @NReilingh That'd be great. Should we wait for graduation before suggesting it to the devs?

Comment: If you make it tag-specific, don’t forget the basses and ukuleles. I have used JTab on uke questions before.